# TimeDimension with Leaflet and Python backend

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, data-science

I am working on showing congestion through a freeway system.

Having difficulties so added a Bounty.

I have created an example I am working through with JS bin here ( https://jsbin.com/lebeqam/edit?html,js,output )

I have created a leaflet map with the detectors lat long and id numbers.

I also have a csv with occupancy data, a important traffic value, over time for each detector.

I am wondering how I should go about creating a heatmap with this data that shows on the map. I would like to be able to change the time and even play the time forward or backward to get an understanding of congestion and how to stop it at it's root.

This is html and jscript for the page currently with some parts removed

```
    <div id="mapid" style="height:1858px; border-right: 1px solid #d7d7d7; position: fixed; top: 0px;width: 67%;z-index: 0;cursor: -webkit-grab;cursor: -moz-grab;background: #fff;
    color: #404040;color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);outline: 0;overflow: hidden;-ms-touch-action: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;"></div>

  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

</body>


<script>

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i>',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'dummy' // We don't want to use the default class
});

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-37.735018, 144.894947], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.geoJSON(myGeojsonData, {
    pointToLayer: function (getJsonPoint, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, { icon: myIcon });
    }
}).bindPopup(function(layer) {
    return 'ID #: ' + layer.feature.properties.IDnumber + '<br />Area: ' + layer.feature.properties.Area;
}).addTo(mymap);

    var circle = L.circle([-37.735018, 144.894947], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 50
}).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

This is part of the geoJson (the entire file is huge but you'll get the picture)

```
var myGeojsonData =
{
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          144.829434,
          -37.825233
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Area": "Combined Entry MVT on Grieve Pde, West Gate Fwy North Ramps, Grieve Pde Byp Start EB between Grieve ",
        "IDnumber": "2541EL_P0"
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },...etc
```

And this is the CSV with the traffic data (also only a part of it for the sake of space.)

[image: Traffic Occupancy]

I have tried to simplify this a bit by using these two json files to just get going (the time series file is in the jsbin as it's too large for stackoverflow.

```
var myGeojsonData =
{
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          144.827465,
          -37.82572
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Area": "Freeway MVT on West Gate Fwy WB between Grieve Pde Off Ramp (ob) & Split To PFW and WRR",
        "IDnumber": "7859OB_L_P0"
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    },
    ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
;
```

If anyone could show me how they would approach this that would be brilliant.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a fair bit of work to do to make a functional application but I've had a quick go at evolving your jsbin to do most of the "bits" of what you need.

I made up some additional fake data and included it at "7859OB_L_P1" in the jsbin.

Essentially I have:

- restructured the example data to be a little more useful for building the heatmaps (though...it might actually be better to use these to prepare the data in the format expected by the heatmap library)

  `i.e. [[lat, lng, value], ...] rather than {'Time':[...], 'Data':{...}}`
- Used the nouislider library recommended by [istopopoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1892308/istopopoki)
- Used an existing leaflet plugin to draw the heatmaps: [leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat)

Most of the new "work" is done in the slider update call. You can see it here: https://jsbin.com/jeguwif/edit?html,js,output

```
// Register an update handler on the slider which:
//  - Updates the "timeSelected" element
//  - Calculates the new data for the time
//  - sets the values into the heatmap and updates the "max" value
//
//  NB: if there is LOTS of data, it might be too slow to recalculate these
//      on every change, in which case perhaps building the [lat, lng, val] arrays
//      for each time up front might be a better idea
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
  var index = Number(values[0])

  timeSelected.value = tabular['Time'][index]
  var dataRow = tabular['Data'][index]
   // play with this val for scaling, i.e. depends how zoomed you are etc
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, dataRow) * 1.0
  var heatValues = tabular['Locations'].map((loc, idx) => {
    return [].concat(locationCoords[loc]).concat(dataRow[idx])
  })

  heat.setOptions({max: max})
  heat.setLatLngs(heatValues.concat(heatValues).concat(heatValues))

});
```

Additionally, I have added the script inclusions in the HTML head section.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. I have started playing around with the data in python but I will use a smaller amount of data to begin with just to test the idea.

Comment: If I can just ask some questions,

Comment: In the jsbin, what is this doing exactly?

example["7859OB_L_P1"] = Object.keys(example["Time"]).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = example["7859OB_L_P0"][key] * (1.5-Math.random())
  return acc
},{})

var locationCoords = myGeojsonData['features'].reduce(
  (acc, obj) => {
    var coords = obj['geometry']['coordinates'];
    acc[obj['properties']['IDnumber']] = [coords[1], coords[0]]
    return acc
  }, {})

Comment: Just going through the javascript that is transforming the data to get an understanding of exactly how it is doing that so I can put in more data sources to get a prototype working - any explanation on how your transofmring the data would be brilliant. I'll change how the data is structured with python in line with your comments above at a later point!

Comment: G'day mate, unforts I'm in a different timezone, so will always be a bit slow to respond...anyway... the "7859OB_L_P1" stuff is just creating a second series of fake data with the Math.random() function. I tried copying the "7859OB_L_P0" one, but JSBin has a limit on the size of a gist.

I'll go and edit the actual gist now to include comments about the transformations. The reality is that there are many (probably better) ways to do it.

Comment: Ok, I've make the example a bin more linear and added some comments. It's probably a good idea for you to clone the example and play around with it. There are a few commented out console.log() calls that might help show what is happening.

Comment: Thanks - having a good look through today as I'm back at work. 

Thinking of the best way to get the data together so I can process it effectively. Maybe just getting a series of detectors with occupancy over 30 minute intervals for a day would be ffective to showcase what this does?

Comment: I guess it depends a lot on what you are trying to show/build. If it is a tool for people to explore the data for themselves it will look pretty different from a tool you are using for your own goals (i.e. to find quickly where do go looking). If I were you I would spend some time writing down a few hypotheses (i.e. 5-10 if you can) about what you believe might be present, and then move on to figuring out what visualisations/tools can help you prove/disprove them. Additionally, don't be afraid to use what you know from the real world...i.e. peak hour is a thing, weekend sport is a thing.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will write down those hypothesis's after i get the prototype going. This is my latest jsbin https://jsbin.com/detejef/edit?html,js,console,output . It's almost perfect except I've got more data points and occupancy over only 1 hr intervals. Isn't showing up which I'm not 100% sure why

Comment: Hey man - could you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034833/input-data-from-slider-to-change-marker-colour

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

1. create a function taking a date as argument that will display the data on your map only for that date. Or two arguments (startDate, enDate), and your function will display the data between those two dates. This function has to filter the data, and display it.
2. create a function that clears all the data on the map.
3. Next to the map, add a slider. Or date pickers, or anything that gives the possibility to choose a start and end date. You can for example use [nouislider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/). When the user changes the dates range, you can [bind something to that event](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/). What you will bind is a function that first clears the map (ie call the function of step 2) and display the new data (ie call the function of step 1).

Comment: Would it be worthwhile doing this in python instead of javascript somehow?

Comment: At some point, if there is too much data, loading all the data client side and filtering with js is going to be slow. A solution is then to filter server side (with python for example). The answer above remains unchanged, but the event described in step 3 will make a request to your python backend, the filtered data are sent back to the client and leaflet displays it.

Comment: So for the first step - Should I transfer this CSV data to Json?

Comment: There is a plugin to load directly a csv into a geojson layer : https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV