# input data from slider to change marker colour

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

Appreciate any help on this task!

I'm trying to have this dash app take slider input value to change a variable through a function and then change the marker colour variable only.

The code is written in python and uses plotly-dash and plotly and as well as pandas numpy and mapbox.

The top part of the code is getting the data into the right format. It has traffic data which is being processed to product a heatmap that shows congestion over time on a map. The dataframe DF is for volume of traffic, and the dataframe HF was created so the slider would work (i added a column numbered 0 to number of columns to use with the slider) - the function datatime should choose the volumes based on the time and the detector ID.

I originally created this functionality with javascript as shown here - https://jsbin.com/detejef/edit?html,js,output

I've been working at this code for awhile. Very close to finally getting a prototype but have this one snag - the variable of time doesn't update properly and reupdate the map with the detector changes...

I just need marker dictionary sub function colour to change with the slider value changing in conjunction with the functions I've created. The function works by itself.

This is an update to the code.

```
#  data wrangling

xls = pd.ExcelFile('FreewayFDSData.xlsx')  # this loads the data only once saving memory
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Volume', parse_dates=True, index_col="Time")
df = df.T

df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Occupancy', parse_dates=True, index_col="Time")
df2 = df2.T

df3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Speed', parse_dates=True, index_col="Time")
df3 = df3.T

Detectors = list(df.columns)

mf = pd.read_excel('FreewayFDSData.xlsx', 'Coordinates', index_col="Short Name")

#   return df, df2, df3, Detectors, mf


# input slider value then output into data frame filter for slider time volume value

# timeslider arrangement
def heatmap(SVO):
    # creates heatmap data for map
    SVO['Period'] = np.arange(len(SVO))
    mintime = SVO['Period'].min()
    maxtime = SVO['Period'].max()
    return mintime, maxtime


mintime, maxtime = heatmap(df)

hf = df.reset_index().set_index('Period')

df2['Period'] = np.arange(len(df2))
hf2 = df2.reset_index().set_index('Period')
df3['Period'] = np.arange(len(df3))
hf3 = df.reset_index().set_index('Period')
# Marker

def datatime(t,hf):
    heat = hf.filter(items=[t], axis=0).T.drop("index")
    return heat[t]
```

This is the app section with only the useful parts included.

```
                   ..... 
html.Div([
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='tdatam',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Volume', 'Speed', 'Occupancy']],
        value='Volume',
        labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
],
    style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

html.Div([
    ....
    ],
        style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    html.P("", id="popupAnnotation", className="popupAnnotation"),
    dcc.Slider(
        id="Slider",
        marks={i: 'Hour {}'.format(i) for i in range(0, 24)},
        min=mintime / 4,
        max=maxtime / 4,
        step=.01,
        value=9,
    )
], style={"padding-bottom": '50px', "padding-right": '50px', "padding-left": '50px', "padding-top": '50px'}),
        ....
```

App functions/ callbacks

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),

    [Input('Slider', 'value'),
     Input('tdatam', 'value')]

)
def update_map(time, tdata):
    #use state 
    zoom = 10.0
    latInitial = -37.8136
    lonInitial = 144.9631
    bearing = 0
    #when time function is updated from slider it is failing
    #Trying to create either a new time variable to create a test for time slider or alternatively a new function for updating time
    if tdata == "Volume":
        return go.Figure(
            data=Data([
                Scattermapbox(
                    lat=mf.Y,
                    lon=mf.X,
                    mode='markers',
                    hoverinfo="text",
                    text=["Monash Freeway", "Western Link",
                          "Eastern Link",
                          "Melbourne CBD", "Swan Street"],
                    # opacity=0.5,
                    marker=Marker(size=15,
                                  color=datatime(time,hf),
                                  colorscale='Viridis',
                                  opacity=.8,
                                  showscale=True,
                                  cmax=2500,
                                  cmin=700
                                  ),
                ),
            ]),
            layout=Layout(
                autosize=True,
                height=750,
                margin=Margin(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0),
                showlegend=False,
                mapbox=dict(
                    accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                    center=dict(
                        lat=latInitial,  # -37.8136
                        lon=lonInitial  # 144.9631
                    ),
                    style='dark',
                    bearing=bearing,
                    zoom=zoom
                ),........
                    )
                ]
            )
        )
```

Example data (anonamized)

```
Lat/Long/Name

Short Name  Y   X
A   -37.883416  145.090084
B   -37.883378  145.090038
C   -37.882968  145.089531
D   -37.882931  145.089484



Data input
Row Labels  00:00 - 00:15   00:15 - 00:30   00:30 - 00:45   00:45 - 01:00   01:00 - 01:15   01:15 - 01:30   01:30 - 01:45   01:45 - 02:00   02:00 - 02:15   02:15 - 02:30   02:30 - 02:45   02:45 - 03:00   03:00 - 03:15   03:15 - 03:30   03:30 - 03:45   03:45 - 04:00   04:00 - 04:15   04:15 - 04:30   04:30 - 04:45   04:45 - 05:00   05:00 - 05:15   05:15 - 05:30   05:30 - 05:45   05:45 - 06:00   06:00 - 06:15   06:15 - 06:30   06:30 - 06:45   06:45 - 07:00   07:00 - 07:15   07:15 - 07:30   07:30 - 07:45   07:45 - 08:00   08:00 - 08:15   08:15 - 08:30   08:30 - 08:45   08:45 - 09:00   09:00 - 09:15   09:15 - 09:30   09:30 - 09:45   09:45 - 10:00   10:00 - 10:15   10:15 - 10:30   10:30 - 10:45   10:45 - 11:00   11:00 - 11:15   11:15 - 11:30   11:30 - 11:45   11:45 - 12:00   12:00 - 12:15   12:15 - 12:30   12:30 - 12:45   12:45 - 13:00   13:00 - 13:15   13:15 - 13:30   13:30 - 13:45   13:45 - 14:00   14:00 - 14:15   14:15 - 14:30   14:30 - 14:45   14:45 - 15:00   15:00 - 15:15   15:15 - 15:30   15:30 - 15:45   15:45 - 16:00   16:00 - 16:15   16:15 - 16:30   16:30 - 16:45   16:45 - 17:00   17:00 - 17:15   17:15 - 17:30   17:30 - 17:45   17:45 - 18:00   18:00 - 18:15   18:15 - 18:30   18:30 - 18:45   18:45 - 19:00   19:00 - 19:15   19:15 - 19:30   19:30 - 19:45   19:45 - 20:00   20:00 - 20:15   20:15 - 20:30   20:30 - 20:45   20:45 - 21:00   21:00 - 21:15   21:15 - 21:30   21:30 - 21:45   21:45 - 22:00   22:00 - 22:15   22:15 - 22:30   22:30 - 22:45   22:45 - 23:00   23:00 - 23:15   23:15 - 23:30   23:30 - 23:45   23:45 - 24:00
A   88  116 84  68  76  56  56  48  72  48  76  40  76  44  36  76  76  116 124 176 236 352 440 624 1016    1172    1260    1280    1304    1312    1252    1344    1324    1336    1212    1148    1132    1120    1084    996 924 1040    952 900 900 1116    1136    1044    1144    1152    1224    1088    1132    1184    1208    1120    1240    1196    1116    1264    1196    1240    1308    1192    1164    1096    1080    1160    1112    1244    1244    1184    1232    996 1108    876 864 776 644 520 684 724 632 620 680 724 516 504 432 396 264 252 272 256 100 144
B   88  116 76  68  76  56  56  48  68  48  76  48  80  44  32  76  76  108 120 180 240 340 456 624 1088    1268    1352    1384    1412    1376    1356    1372    1400    1436    1296    1240    1200    1256    1120    1028    1008    1072    980 944 932 1148    1192    1040    1188    1220    1292    1140    1116    1268    1292    1172    1272    1236    1216    1280    1248    1280    1388    1244    1224    1076    1096    1148    1108    1256    1356    1308    1236    992 1100    880 872 768 640 520 680 720 636 620 660 716 512 504 428 396 260 244 272 252 100 136
C   84  108 68  68  72  56  56  36  60  48  76  44  72  48  32  68  76  108 124 176 240 340 436 604 1036    1168    1280    1372    1204    1304    1268    1228    1280    1312    1164    1076    1156    1108    924 960 864 944 896 840 840 1068    1052    1036    1128    1164    1136    1084    1052    1136    1072    1056    1136    1160    1088    1224    1180    1228    1264    1204    1044    1008    1076    1128    1112    1252    1188    1180    1156    1000    1096    860 868 736 600 520 680 704 624 616 684 720 500 504 408 392 252 236 264 240 96  144
D   92  108 68  68  72  56  56  40  64  48  76  44  72  48  32  72  76  112 132 184 240 340 436 608 1040    1156    1280    1336    1196    1336    1316    1272    1344    1332    1144    1140    1176    1128    924 948 888 956 892 848 868 1036    1064    1036    1108    1192    1120    1080    1044    1152    1068    1040    1140    1180    1104    1232    1164    1280    1256    1196    1052    1016    1084    1128    1116    1252    1192    1168    1160    1000    1076    868 872 744 620 524 680 716 628 628 680 716 500 500 412 388 256 244 260 244 96  144
```

The key issue I have determined is that HF is not being pulled into the function after the initial call. I am not sure why - it should work just as the time value on the slider changes. The function itself clearly works though - it is definitely that HF is not being brought into def update_map.

Comment: Hey Michael, unfortunately this question is a bit impenetrable....there is a lot of code here, most of which I don't think is related to your question. If you can distill your problem down a little that would be good....i.e. something more like "I have a Marker, and I want to change the color. The way I create it is this...I want to update it like this, but it doesn't work with this code".

Comment: definitely let me change the code a bit!!!!

Comment: Doddie hope that can help you!

Comment: Happy to give you more bounty :D

Comment: Hey, I've had another read, but I still don't really understand the question. I wouldn't offer any more bounty, you've spent enough. Try not to spend so much time explaining how you're doing thing....just state the problem...i..e I still have no idea what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the slider was inputing values like 9.19 which has no column to filter too.

The way i solved this issue was too implement a floor using numpy array through the datetime function. this meant it only used values that were full number integers.